# Lotus Domino HTTP: Define MIME types

Tags: http, ibm-domino, mime-type

My Lotus Domino 9.0 server serves the application cache manifest as `application/octet-stream`, where the browser expects `text/cache-manifest`.

I only found examples how to add a MIME type to Apache and IIS. Do you know how to add a MIME type to Domino HTTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a 'File Identification' Document to the Domino Directory.

Goto the 'Web\File Identifications' folder and click 'Add File Indentification'.

Example:

MIME type: text
MIME subtype: cache-manifest
File extension: appcache

This would allow Domino to corretly process manifest files, using the recommended extension, such as 'offline.appcache'

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is the httpd.cnf file in the domino data directory which can control various MIME mappings.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607140/control-mime-type-for-downloads-in-domino for a little more info with example.